# Can the same ability be triggered multiple times?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

Can abilities be triggered multiple times as long as the cost is paid?  The Physical Training asset card has a free triggered ability that says

> Spend 1 resource: You get +1 Willpower for this skill test

Does this mean I can spend 3 resource to get +3 willpower?

Can I assume that as long as abilities don't say "once per ___" that I can figure they can be used as long as the cost can be paid right then and there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that ability is a "free triggered ability" (RRG, page 3) and may be triggered in any player ability window as many times as you would like, so long as you can pay the cost (in this case, 1 resource).

One aside is to note that it says "You get...", so you cannot use talent cards such as these to buff other investigators.